# Zend DB - where And Or Query

Tags: php, sql, zend-db

Could someone please tell me the correct syntax for a Zend DB query to represent the last line (the `and (xxx or xxx)`

```
...
where
    id = 1241487470
and (contract=0 or is_work IS NOT NULL)
...
```

I'm stuck at this:

```
->where('id = ?', 1241487470)
->where(...)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seemed logical and worked. So Yay.

```
->where('id = ?', 1241487470)
->where('contract= ? or is_work IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: This is the correct way of handling this situation. However did you mean Zend DB rather than Form?

Comment: Yes I did :) must have been a long day. I've corrected it. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

This seems works too and preserve zend db escapement

```
->where('id = ?', 1241487470);
->where('(contract = ?', 0);
->orWhere('is_work IS NOT NULL)');
```